# how to replace a string not followed by dot and at the end of the line

Tags: sed

I have a line

```
echo "object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp"
object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp
```

and I need to replace the smtp with 25 but just were the `smtp` is standing alone. The expected output should be

```
object 25 aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq 25
```

It is not possible to use the \b or  < > boundaries because there is a comma. I've tried to use

```
echo "object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq 25" | sed -E 's/smtp[^.]?$/25/g'
object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq 25
```

but it replaces just match at the end of the line. The

```
echo "object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp" | sed -E 's/smtp[^.]?( |$)/25/g'
object 25aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq 25
```

replaces also the space. Does somebody has an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: You can use `sed -E 's/(^| )smtp($| )/\125\2/g'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/HevGKs))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That won't work with `'smtp smtp'`

Comment: @anubhava I know that, if OP had `smtp smtp`, I'd advise `sed -E ':a;s/(^| )smtp($| )/\125\2/;ta'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/7ufVeE))

Comment: SamG, following your exact requirements, can you please confirm you want to replace `smtp` in `... smtp-server ...`? Try `sed -E ':a;s/(^|[^.])smtp($|[^.])/\125\2/;ta'` then.

Comment: You did not mention you actually want to restrict the left-hand boundary, so even `sed -E 's/smtp($|[^.])/25\1/;g'` should work. If `smtp` must be a whole word you can still try ``sed -E 's/\bsmtp($|[^.])/25\1/;g'`` (for GNU sed).

Comment: How about something [like this?](https://tio.run/##HYm9CoAgEIBf5XLJhhSCtsCHaG257Egi0Txp6t0N3b6fHdmVQtYFEGG/yGZgnyMgYgOFfCgbPDCll5JqrTo97Qv4IFK6YYwEPWtplm5bh7qkqaSnWZ99KT8)

Comment: Regarding `it is not possible to use the \b or < > boundaries because there is a comma` - if a comma is stopping you from using a solution, then include commas (and any other relevant chars/strings) in your example so you don't get answers to some other problem than the one you actually have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just need to replace the whole smtp string. So the `smtp-server`  string should stay the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
s="object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp"
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/(^|[[:blank:]])smtp([[:blank:]]|$)/\125\2/g;ta' <<< "$s"

object 25 aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq 25
```

Here:

- `:a`: Sets label `a`
- `s/(^|[[:blank:]])smtp([[:blank:]]|$)/\125\2/g` replaces each `smtp` with `25` if it preceded by start position or whitespace and if it is followed by whitespace or end position
- `ta`: Goes back to label `a` if substitution is successful

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/efxKDP)

Answer (score 0):

With a GNU sed, if you need to match `smpt` as a whole word that has no dot at the end, you can use

```bash
s="object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp"
sed -E 's/\bsmtp([^.]|$)/25\1/g' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TRI6ht). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `smtp` - `smtp` substring
- `([^.]|$)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` refers to this value in the replacement): any char other than a `.` char (`[^.]`), or (`|`) the end of string (`$`).

The same can be done with `perl`:

```bash
s="object smtp aaa smtp.asd.com server.smtp.com eq smtp"
perl -pe 's/\bsmtp\b(?!\.)/25/g' <<< "$s"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/wwKPEO).

Here, `\bsmtp\b(?!\.)` matches a whole word `smtp` (with `\bsmtp\b`) that is not immediately followed with a `.` char (`(?!\.)`).

Another solution with `perl` is to match `smtp` within whitespace boundaries:

```bash
perl -pe 's/(?<!\S)smtp(?!\S)/25/g' <<< "$s"
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/kHi37o). *However*, in this case, it won't replace `smtp` in `smtp-server` since `smtp` in this case should be inside whitespaces or start/end of string.